# Go gin framework CORS

Tags: go, frameworks, cors, preflight, go-gin

I'm using Go gin framework [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin)

```
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, UPDATE")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, X-Max")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(200)
        } else {
            c.Next()
        }
    }
}
```

I've got Status Code:200 OK, but nothing happens after OPTIONS request. 
It looks like I miss something, but I can't understand where am I wrong.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

FWIW, this is my CORS Middleware that works for my needs.

```
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why 204? Why not 200?

Comment: HTTP NoContent coz duh!

Comment: Almost 6 years old and still great. Fixed my problem in no time. Yet I wonder why this is not part of the official documentation on github...

Comment: Thanks @Jack . Able to add this only at the root of the application. Not working only for group routes of the application for which i added some conditions based on the route url.

Comment: `c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` this may cause browser get into cors issue, in that case need to specify specific origin instead of `*`.

Comment: [Not all `OPTIONS` requests are CORS-preflight requests](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly), though. Also, as pointed out by @Eric, you're ignoring the [wildcard exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards).

Answer (score 29):

There is also official gin's middleware for handling CORS requests [github.com/gin-contrib/cors](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors).

You could install it using `$ go get github.com/gin-contrib/cors` and then add this middleware in your application like this:
package main

```
import (
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    // CORS for https://foo.com and https://github.com origins, allowing:
    // - PUT and PATCH methods
    // - Origin header
    // - Credentials share
    // - Preflight requests cached for 12 hours
    router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"https://foo.com"},
        AllowMethods:     []string{"PUT", "PATCH"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin"},
        ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        AllowOriginFunc: func(origin string) bool {
            return origin == "https://github.com"
        },
        MaxAge: 12 * time.Hour,
    }))
    router.Run()
}
```

Comment: If you use `AllowOriginFunc` your origins defined in `AllowOrigins` will be ignored. `AllowOriginFunc is a custom function to validate the origin. It take the origin as argument and returns true if allowed or false otherwise. If this option is set, the content of AllowOrigins is ignored.`

Answer (score 21):

I spent like an hour to get why some example from the internet works, and some doesn't. So I got the difference - line order is important, **fristly you should use config and then declare your endpoints**, but not the opposite way.

Works:

```
router := gin.Default()
router.Use(cors.Default())
router.GET("/ping", pong)
router.Run(":8082")
```

Doesn't work:

```
router := gin.Default()
router.GET("/ping", pong)
router.Use(cors.Default())
router.Run(":8082")
```

Answer (score 14):

```
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {

        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,HEAD,PATCH, OPTIONS, GET, PUT")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

then use it

```
router = gin.New()  
router.Use(CORSMiddleware())
```

Answer (score 6):

There is package https://github.com/rs/cors, that handles CORS requests in the right way. It has the examples for the popular routers including `gin`. That it:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    cors "github.com/rs/cors/wrapper/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.Use(cors.Default())
    router.GET("/", func(context *gin.Context) {
        context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"hello": "world"})
    })

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

In common case, you just add the default handling with `router.Use(cors.Default())` to your middlewares in `gin`. It is enough.

Answer (score 3):

We created a minimal middleware.

```
import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)

type optionsMiddleware struct {

}

func CreateOptionsMiddleware() *optionsMiddleware{
    return &optionsMiddleware{}
}

func (middleware *optionsMiddleware)Response(context *gin.Context){
    if context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        context.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
    }
}
```

and register it with gin middleware :

```
app  := gin.New()
app.Use(middleware.CreateOptionsMiddleware().Response).
    Use(next-middleware)......
```

Comment: Careful. Not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests.

Answer (score 3):

With `gin-contrib/cors`

```golang
import "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"

[...]

router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:4040"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"GET"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"Content-Type", "Content-Length", "Accept-Encoding", "Authorization", "Cache-Control"},
    ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
}))
```

In my case, I had a JWT token middleware before this one that blocked all OPTION pre-flight requests. Putting the CORS middleware first solved the problem.

Comment: Because `Accept-Encoding` and `Content-Length` are so-called _forbidden request-headers_ ([per the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header)), listing them as allowed headers in your CORS configuration is useless.

Answer (score 3):

> It looks like I miss something, but I can't understand where am I wrong.

Because CORS is more complex a protocol than meets the eye, implementing it by "manually" setting CORS response headers is error-prone. In this specific case,

- you've likely hit the so-called [*wildcard exception*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards), which disallows the use of the wildcard (`*`) in conjunction with credentialed requests;
- you're also attempting to allow [request headers that the Fetch standard categorises as *forbidden*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header), but browsers silently ignore client attempts to include such headers in requests.

These difficulties may be enough to convince you that, in general, you're better off relying on a good CORS middleware library, which can abstract all this complexity away from you.

Gin does have an official CORS middleware library: [gin-contrib/cors](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors), but it's far from ideal; I've written at length about this topic in [a recent blog post](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/). If [gin-contrib/cors](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors) leaves you dissatisfied, perhaps you'll appreciate my own CORS middleware library: [jub0bs/cors](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jub0bs/cors). It's designed to be, not only easier to use, but also *harder to misuse*.

It's primarily compatible with `http.Handler`, but it can be used in conjunction with Gin via a `http.Handler`-to-`gin.HandleFunc` adapter, such as that provided by [gwatts/gin-adapter](https://github.com/gwatts/gin-adapter):

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    adapter "github.com/gwatts/gin-adapter"
    "github.com/jub0bs/cors"
)

func main() {
    // create an engine
    engine := gin.Default()

    // configure the CORS middleware
    corsMw, err := cors.NewMiddleware(cors.Config{
        Origins: []string{"*"},
        Methods: []string{
            http.MethodGet,
            http.MethodPost,
            http.MethodPut,
            http.MethodDelete,
            "UPDATE",
        },
        RequestHeaders: []string{
            "Authorization",
            "Content-Type",
            "X-CSRF-Token",
            "X-Max",
        },
        MaxAgeInSeconds: 86400,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // apply the CORS middleware to the engine
    engine.Use(adapter.Wrap(corsMw.Wrap))

    // register the hello handler for the /hello route
    engine.GET("/hello", hello)

    // start the server on port 8080
    if err := engine.Run(":8080"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func hello(ctx *gin.Context) {
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"hello": "world"})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me - NOTE: the setting of header directly.

```
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {

        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        /*
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers")
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH")
        */

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me too, that `cors.Default()` got me nowhere, tks.

Comment: Careful. Not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` and `c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")`. Either specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to a specific domain or set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to false.

```golang
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, UPDATE")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, X-Max")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
        } else {
            c.Next()
        }
    }
```

or if the origin is `http://localhost:3000`

```golang
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, UPDATE")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, X-Max")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
        } else {
            c.Next()
        }
    }
```

Comment: The condition `c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS"` is too restrictive: not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests. See https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other answers using `gin-contrib/cors` - apparently `DefaultConfig()` is important.

What caused the same issue for me:

```
router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins: []string{
        "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    },
}))
```

What worked for me:

```
corsConfig := cors.DefaultConfig()
corsConfig.AllowOrigins = []string{
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
}
router.Use(cors.New(corsConfig))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using a react app as "source of http calls".
I tried to use many of suggestions in this thread, but apparently none of them worked.

Then I looked at the browser network develop tab, when then i realized that react sends an OPTION request, ant at request header there was 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type,user-agent'

At this moment, i added "user-agent" in the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", and then all worked.
The "final" code was:

```
c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With,user-agent")
```

[react](/questions/tagged/react) [cors](/questions/tagged/cors)