# GoLang/Javascript: Empty postForm and decode(body) on JSON POST

Tags: javascript, json, post, go

I'm trying to POST JSON data from a javascript page, into a golang server, but I'm unable to find any trace of the JSON data using the SO accepted answers on both ends.

[*This post*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13038218/4808079) shows the way I'm posting my JSON in Javascript and [*this post*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685432/4808079) shows the way I'm trying to process this JSON in Go.

```
//js json post send
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/aardvark/posts', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

var data = {hat: "fez"};
request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

[The header below was set from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29439630/4808079)

```
//Go json post response
func reply(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT")


    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err);
    }

    //this is my first impulse.  It makes the most sense to me.
    fmt.Println(r.PostForm);          //out -> `map[]`  would be `map[string]string` I think
    fmt.Println(r.PostForm["hat"]);   //out -> `[]`  would be `fez` or `["fez"]`
    fmt.Println(r.Body);              //out -> `&{0xc82000e780 <nil> <nil> false true {0 0} false false false}`


    type Hat struct {
        hat string
    }

    //this is the way the linked SO post above said should work.  I don't see how the r.Body could be decoded.
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var t Hat   
    err := decoder.Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err);
    }
    fmt.Println(t);                  //out -> `{ }`
}
```

I'm not really sure what else to try from here.  What should I change to make this work?

Comment: You're right in using `r.Body`. The reason that it looks so strange when you print it is that you're printing the structure that will let you read the posted contents (that is, the `io.Reader`) rather than the actual contents.

Comment: `ParseForm` would not work because it expects the encoding to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` which are different to json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the field `hat` of the struct `Hat` and json decoding would work.

```
type Hat struct {
    Hat string // Exported field names begins with capital letters
}
```

Comment: For the full details see the [docs for Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal): Unmarshal unmarshals into structs "preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive match. Unmarshal will only set exported fields of the struct"