# How to set http headers for static files?

Tags: go, cors, go-gin

I use gin-gonic's `r.Static("files", "./files")` to serve all files in the `files` directory. Is there a way to set headers for these file requests so I can allow CORS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418478/go-gin-framework-cors/29439630#29439630 and https://github.com/itsjamie/gin-cors and https://skarlso.github.io/2016/02/02/doing-cors-in-go-with-gin-and-json/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [an official Gin middleware](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors) providing this functionality.

A Good starting template (from their examples)

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    // - No origin allowed by default
    // - GET,POST, PUT, HEAD methods
    // - Credentials share disabled
    // - Preflight requests cached for 12 hours
    config := cors.DefaultConfig()
    config.AllowOrigins = []string{"http://google.com"}
    config.AddAllowOrigins("http://facebook.com")
    // config.AllowOrigins == []string{"http://google.com", "http://facebook.com"}

    router.Use(cors.New(config))
    router.Run()
}
```